# Is TCPDF MultiCell maxheight parameter overriding the height parameter even if it wouldn't have to?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdi

I updated my tcpdf lib and I am now facing this weird behaviour that apparently the `maxheight` parameter overrides the `minimum height` parameter, even if it the cell content is not that high.

From the [docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece) it says:

> - $h: (float) Cell minimum height. The cell extends automatically if needed.
> - $maxh: (float) maximum height. It should be >= $h and less then remaining space to the bottom of the page, or 0 for disable this
>     feature. This feature works only when $ishtml=false.

My `$maxh` is higher than `$h`, `$ishtml` is `false`:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 5, "short", 1, 'L', true, 0, 45, 154, true, 0, false, false, 11, 'T', true);
```

So `height` is `5` and `max height` is `11`. The cell is always `11`, even if the content is really short.

How to set the cell height to a min of 5, to a max of 11 and only have it expand when the content actually is so much that a new line would be reached?

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]
and:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might appear a bit unclear in the documentation but you need to disable the `$fitcell` option (it is the last argument of `MultiCell()`) in order to achieve the expected behaviour. The line should look like this:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 5, "short", 1, 'L', true, 0, 45, 154, true, 0, false, false, 11, 'T', false);
```

(Note the `false` instead of `true` at the end).

If `$fitcell` is enabled TCPDF would shrink larger texts to fit the cell by applying a lower font size but it would not attempt to shrink the cell if the text is smaller than the cell.

Since TCPDF would also not attempt to enlarge the cell when `$fitcell` is disabled you would need to increase the max height param to allow more content.

---

Here comes a short example:

```
require_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

// Create new pdf
$pdf = new TCPDF();

// Add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Set color for background
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 127);

// Add 2 cells
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 5, "one line", 1, 'L', true, 0, 50, 50, true, 0, false, false, 21, 'T', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 5, "badger badger badger badger badger badger badger badger - mushroom! mushroom!", 1, 'L', true, 0, 50, 60, true, 0, false, false, 21, 'T', false);

$pdf->Output();
```

**Rendered:**

[image]

---

In comments you told:

> I do want to shrink the text if the text doesnt fit without shrinking, allowing the cell to expand to a maximum height. in your answer, one line and badger.. are the same font size

If you want to achieve that, you need to disable the `$maxh` feature and enable the `$fitcell` feature, like that:

```
require_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

// Create new pdf
$pdf = new TCPDF();

// Add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Set color for background
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 127);

// Add 2 cells
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 11, "short", 1, 'L', true, 0, 50, 50, true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);
$pdf->MultiCell(59, 11, "badger badger badger badger badger badger badger badger - mushroom! mushroom!", 1, 'L', true, 0, 50, 60, true, 0, false, false, 0, 'T', true);
```

**Rendered:**

[image]

However, now the cell containing "short" will not getting shrinked.

**Note**

After playing with these both examples I realized the problem. Currently I don't see a way how to have both a shrinked box with "short" and a box containing the long text with a lower font size. However, I'll keep my answer, probably it is a good starting point for others.

Comment: i didnt try your answer but i do want to shrink the text if the text doesnt fit without shrinking, allowing the cell to expand to a maximum height. in your answer, `one line` and `badger..` are the same font size

Comment: @Alex Now I got the problem. Currently I don't see a way how it can achieved. Will read the documentation and the related source code. Probably I can find a way.

Comment: You are welcome. Did the code you showed in the question worked in an older version of TCPDF? If yes, which version were you using before?